# Batch - Log off while locked

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7-x64

I want to run a silent installer, lock the computer, then when the install is complete, **have the PC log off, while locked**

The locking will be manual but the rest, ideally I would like to be done through a batch file. I've tried simply trying to set it to log off while locked and that doesn't work so I was wondering if there was a way around it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can lock the screen with `rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation`, do your work and log the user off with `shutdown /l`. You might want to add `/t xxx` and `/f` to shutdown.exe.

Comment: The locking wasn't the issue as that will be manual once we make sure the install has started without issue but pointing me towards /f worked. That logs a user off while locked. Thanks.